# File missing in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I setup a Laravel project with composer command. When I open the browser to access the page I get a fatal error like this:

> `Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'C:\xampp\htdocs\Learning Laravel\bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\Learning Laravel\bootstrap\autoload.php on line 17.`

The file is indeed missing.

So my steps were:

1. I downloaded composer
2. Command in CMD:

   composer create-project laravel/laravel laravel5-learning
   After this I got the error about the missing file.
3. Then I put the suggested command in CMD:

   composer install

But now I get a new error:

```
RuntimeException in EncryptionServiceProvider.php line 29:
No supported encrypter found. The cipher and / or key length are invalid.
```

Comment: Please add all steps you did to install laravel (how)

Comment: Go to the root directory of your application and run `composer install`.

Comment: Ohgodwhy, thank you. The error is fixed, something still doesn't work though.

Comment: `php artisan key:generate` See if that fixes it.

Comment: Yes, it fixed the problem. Thank you, Tim.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @Ohgodwhy says, your first error is caused because something in the vendor's code is missing.

So, using:

```
composer install
```

Will fix it. After that, as @TimLewis says, you may use:

```
php artisan key:generate
```

To generate a valid key in .env, to secure your session and other encrypted data.

Comment: While this is correct, try to avoid answering questions by reiterating other users' comments. At least you expanded on them a bit.

Comment: Sorry if I caused any trouble, I put it there for other people to see both mixed and easy, because in this situation you usually have to `key:generate` after `composer install` to get it working.